# Dynamically sized div - fit text inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a browser-based ebook reader, using the .xml files inside the .epub files as the content.

Now the thing is, a book has 2 pages to look at, and I experience some problems reconstructing it for various screen sizes. Especially the font.
Depending on the screen size, and dynamically in case of maximized/fullscreen/resizing the font should change accordingly to fit the two pages just right.

Below is some code I tried.

```css
#left{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;  // so a variable width.
  height: 100%;
}
#right{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="left">Half page of text</div>
  <div id="right">Other half page of text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code

Comment: Lets see what you have tried already so we can help.

Comment: Here you go, the source code is added.

Comment: I also tried to obtain the width of the parent div, using offsetWidth. Maybe that's some way? Then I do have a fixed width I could use.

Comment: @RichardMacarthy Can you please check this one once more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry - its a bit difficult to tell what you're after here. You have two 50% divs, that's good. When you say: "What I want to have is a page that automatically stretches the page in a dynamically sized div (using percents)." That seems to me to be exactly what you have now. Can you provide more exactly what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I'm pretty new here, you see... It's the text I want to let stretch out to fill the whole div. So, if there is a text inside that fits perfectly on my screen - let's call the width x and the height y - on a screen that has half the size it would be way too much text (a scrollbar would appear). On a screen double the size the text would be too small.So I'm looking for a command that automatically resizes the text to fit in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing about 2 `display:inline` columns 50% is that with some browsers (ahem: IE) 50% isn't always 50%.  So, you'll have random cases where columns don't flow correctly and your layout is jacked up.  Remember, you'll also have to accommodate for margin and padding if you build a homebrew solution.

My personal preference is going with a grid system that has all these bugs hammered out.  There are a ton of them -- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) has a good one, [960 grids](http://960.gs/) stands alone well.

Here's an example with [960.gs](http://960.gs/) for example:

```
<div class="container_12">
   <div class="grid_6 left">
     Left Column
   </div> 
   <div class="grid_6 right">
     Right Column
   </div>   
</div>
```

That's it....pretty simple.  In a nutshell, you're taking a `.container-12` which would be like a row in a table that has 12 columns in it.  Then you put in two divs that are `.grid-6`, or half of `.container-12` each.  If you wanted a one-quarter, three-quarter layout, you'd do `.grid-3` and `.grid-9`  The grids automatically adapt to size as the browser resizes based on percentages with margins and padding accomodated for.

Bootstrap takes it one step further by allowing you to change your layout simply based on size.  For instance, on a computer screen it could be side-by-side, while on an iPad or iPhone it could be one on top of the other.  Again, you can do this with native CSS, but it's not nearly as easy.